# How to detect a magnetic field from a distance?

Tags: arduino, hall-effect, detection, field, magnet

I want to detect a magnetic field, like those of small neodymium magnets, from at least 6 inches away (the further the better, I'd like at least a foot but I won't ask for too much). I'd like to do this on a small board like the Arduino Beetle. And I'd also like to be able to sense polarity. That's it, I just need to be able to detect a small neodymium magnet and possibly it's polarity, nothing more.

I've been reading everything I can on hall sensors but I don't think any of them are capable of detecting a magnet over much of a distance and it seems that the sensor has to be at a certain orientation to the magnet for it to even work. I'm thinking a fluxgate sensor might be what I'm looking for but I'm not sure.

I know it's possible to detect a small magnet from a distance and it's polarity, I just can't find out exactly how.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I suspect it will end up needing to be something like a magnet on a milligram strain gauge as the forces involved are tiny, but run us through exactly what the application is, is 1 part in motion relative to another?

Comment: I just need to be able to detect a magnet, I don't think there needs to be motion involved. There are products on the market the size of a half dollar that do this but I'm sure I can engineer one for a lot less than the $300 price tag they carry.

And they only have iPhone apps. I want to be able to put together an Android app.

Say you close a small magnet in your fist, I want to be able to detect it from at least 6 inches away.

Comment: Many android devices already have a magnetometer, mine was able to sense a 5x15mm magnet from about 6"

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jasen! I ordered a magnetometer for an Arduino, hopefully this works out well lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, say you have a N42 magnet cube of 5x5mm with 1.3T strength, at 150mm (6") the magnetic field is **1.5 microTesla**. Which is not a lot. Even the magnetic field of the planet is more at ~50 microTesla.
See here: https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp?calcType=block

So, I suspect you'd need to be looking into using a compass and detect disturbances with that. Since hall sensors are typically milliTesla range.

You phone has one. See if you can use it to test sensitivity.

Comment: I wasn't sure if my phone had a sensor capable but now I know. So I just need to find a magnetometer for an Arduino and I should be good to go. Hopefully. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @SladeW.Cooper Not every phone has one, but all iPhones do, and most flagship androids.